# WPF custom control not working as expected in Listview

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to put an editabletextblock cutom control in a Listview datatemplate. I'm following [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/thomaslebrun/wpf-how-to-develop-and-editable-textblock) and it works well.

But when i'm put this control in a Listview datatemplate, on double click on the Textblock, the event OnMouseDoubleClick of the custom control is fired but the Textbox is never display.

My Datatemplate :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
     <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
             <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Grid.Column="0">
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                           Margin="0 0 4 0" />
            <localp:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
     </Grid>

<ListView
     ItemTemplate={StaticResource ItemTemplate}
     .... />
```

And i don't know why the OnMouseDoubleClick EditableTextBlock is fired but the inner Textbox is never displayed as expected.

Thanks is advance for your help,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default values of `TextBlockForegroundColorProperty` and  `TextBoxForegroundColorProperty` from null to something else:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBlockForegroundColorProperty = 
   DependencyProperty.Register("TextBlockForegroundColor", 
   typeof(Brush), typeof(EditableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxForegroundColorProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxForegroundColor",
    typeof(Brush), typeof(EditableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));
```

Or set them in you Xaml:

```
  <local:EditableTextBlock  TextBlockForegroundColor="Black" TextBoxForegroundColor="Black" ... />
```

**Edit**

you can set keyboard focus to the TextBox, however, you should set e.Handled to true, or the `OnTextBoxLostFocus` will execute and hides your TextBox.

```
    protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    { 
        base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
        this.m_TextBlockDisplayText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
        this.m_TextBoxEditText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (m_TextBoxEditText.IsKeyboardFocusWithin ==false)
        {
            Keyboard.Focus(m_TextBoxEditText);
            e.Handled = true;
           m_TextBoxEditText.CaretIndex = m_TextBoxEditText.Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i did that before (sorry if i havn't specified it) because it was transparent. But the problem is the same : in a listview when i double click the EditableTextBlock, the Textbox is never showed. Thanks.

Comment: see my edit. If you have not changed the code in the provided link, this works.